# Navigation menu is showing on top of the website, even though it's translated it up

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a [video](https://gyazo.com/ec047eb14b54086657e59b12200402b4) of the issue. And not sure why this problem is occurring when I decrease the height in responsive design mode. Beginner web developer, any help appreciated.

```
.main-navigation {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: -100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fffefc;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: all 500ms;
}

/* modifier class*/
.navigation-open {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

```
const closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-nav-btn");
const openButton = document.querySelector(".open-nav-btn");
const nav = document.querySelector(".main-navigation");

closeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  nav.classList.remove("navigation-open");
});

openButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  nav.classList.add("navigation-open");
});
```

Let me know if further info is required to help out. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `top: -100%` you have means "move the navigation to the top of the containing block's height". When you resize, the containing block's height is becoming smaller than your navigation's height, which is causing this overflow you see.

A solution could be doing as below.
Notice I'm animating the `height` of the navigation, instead its `top` property.

```
.main-navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: #fffefc;
  transition: all 500ms;
}

.navigation-open {
   overflow:auto;
   height: 100vh;
}
```